# Issues with mail in Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email

I'm setting up postfix using ubuntu, I'm currently following along with [this](https://poweruphosting.com/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04-2/) guide. While doing so I'm at the part of creating my `Maildir` by executing `echo 'init' | mail -s 'init' -Snorecord <USERNAME>`. While executing this command, I get the following error:

```
serveradmin@tmagic:~$ echo 'init' | mail -s 'init' -Snorecord serveradmin
mail: invalid option -- 's'
serveradmin@magic:~$
```

Looking a little deeper into this I tried to send an email just to see what would happen and received the following error:

```
serveradmin@magic:~$ mail -v user@example.com
subject: test
test
.
ignoring system configuration file /etc/msmtprc: No such file or directory
ignoring user configuration file /home/serveradmin/.msmtprc: No such file or directory
falling back to default account
mail: account default not found: no configuration file available
serveradmin@magic:~$
```

What is causing this issue and how can I fix it? I'm running an `Ubuntu 16.04` server.

Comment: You default MTA set to ``msmtp`` instead of ``postfix``

Comment: @Alex awh, you're correct, how can I switch it?

Comment: Simplest way is to ``apt-get purge msmtp-mta`` then reinstall ``postfix`` or you can edit symlink  ``/usr/sbin/sendmail`` so it will point to ``postfix`` instead of ``msmtp-mta``